# Windows based network backup for MySQL, Linux, and Windows Servers (Zmanda alternative for windows?)

Tags: linux, windows-server-2003, mysql, backup

I am looking for Windows based backup software with functionality like Zmanda or other multi-platform network backup software program. Open source or free software is always preferred.

We need to be able to backup files from linux and windows servers as well as MySQL databases. Using samba is completely possible. Software needs to run on Windows Server 2003.

Answer (score 0):

http://blogs.zdnet.com/open-source/?p=2993